# I don't get the "onPushTokenReceivedCallback when" i use my phone

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, notifications, nativescript

I dont get the token when i use my iphone. I get the token when i use the simulator.
I use nativescript-firebase-plugin and in main.js i do the firebase.init functions.

I have tried with everything i have found on this error, or i dont even know if its a common error. The full init looks like this

````
firebase.init({
  showNotifications: true,
  showNotificationsWhenInForeground: true,

  onPushTokenReceivedCallback: (token) => {
    console.log(`onPushTokenReceivedCallback: ${token}`);
    appSettings.setString('firebasemessagekeytoken', token);
  },

  onMessageReceivedCallback: (message) => {
    console.log(`onPushTokenReceivedCallback: ${message.title}`);
  }
})
  .then(() => {
    console.log('[Firebase] Initialized');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(`error: ${error}`);
  });```
````

Comment: Did you see the permission dialog? Did you try `getCurrentPushToken()` method?

Comment: Yes i did, and i see nothing, the only thing i se is the ``` .then(() => {
    console.log('[Firebase] Initialized');
  }) ```

Comment: Is it a production build or debug build? Did you configure the essential certificates on Firebase settings?

Comment: It works on the simulator, on the simulator i get the token and i can recieve notification. I have done everything correct i think, i have made so i can send a message with postman to the device token. So i dont understand why i dont get the token when i use my iphone. I plugged the iphone in and did tns run --device (id)

Comment: I also get this in the terminal ``` 6.9.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at: ````

Comment: @Manoj i fixed it! But now i have another problem, i dont se the notification on the scree, i just se it on the terminal

Comment: You may not see the notification on notification center if app is on foreground. You will have to enable it explicitly, there is a config in messaging docs.

Comment: @Manoj i dont se the notification if im on the app, i never se the notification, i have no idea why, i have all the settings correct

Comment: How are you triggering the notification? Do you see the success message back form Firebase?

Comment: @Manoj yes, i see the notification on the terminal, i can send the message from firebase or postman,  both works. But the only code i have is the firebase.init code piece you se up there. Do i need something more in main.js?